# Load standalone html file in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing using jQuery mobile and it has a multipage template as below.
I feel that writing html content inside the same html is bloated.

As such, i would like to separate the content in different html and include standalone html page. It should be mobile browser proven. What is the best practice on this and how it could be done?

Note: I do not expect server side scripting (eg: PHP) to solve this problem. It should be done solely on client side without any templating engine. Something like angularJS `ng-include`.

Sample of what i expect

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo1">
    <html-include src="foo1.html"></html-include>
</div>
```

Mobile html multipage

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo1">
    <!-- Content 1 here -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="foo2">
    <!-- Content 2 here -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="foo3">
    <!-- Content 3 here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You could use ajax to include the pages accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo1" data-url="foo1.html">

</div>
```

And use javascript like so:

```
$('[data-url]').each(function (k,elem){
    $(elem).load(elem.data('url'));
});
```

This will find all elements that have data-url as attribute, and load that page in AJAX, takes the html received and put in it the corresponding html element.

Comment: so, what do you need then?

Comment: should just need the data attribute ... and an explanation of how it works

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand, you never said there was any framework... The data attributes are just arbitrary attributes. Use whatever you want. And for how it works, it's just a plain ajax call...

Comment: Question is tagged `jQuery mobile` which handles `data-url` internally